# Proof of integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, proof-writing, solution-verification

I try prove this definition but i don't know if this right. (Using definition of U(f,P) and L(f,P) of Calculus Spivak)

$\int ^a_b f=-\int ^b_a f$

suppose f is integrable in [a,b] if $\varepsilon >0$, $\exists $ $P=$ { $t_0,...,t_n$} such that

U(f,P)-L(f,P)< $\varepsilon$

but U(f,P)-L(f,P)=-(-U(f,P)+L(f,P))=-(L(f,P)-U(f,P))<$\varepsilon$

and $Q=$ { $t_0,...,t_n$} there before -U(f,P)=L(f,Q) and -L(f,P)=U(f,Q)

then U(f,P)-L(f,P)=-(-U(f,P)+L(f,P))=-(L(f,P)-U(f,P))=U(f,Q)-L(f,Q)<$\varepsilon$

then $\int ^a_b f=-\int ^b_a f$

Comment: This is a definition and you are not supposed to prove it.

Comment: I disagree that it is a definition. If one is taking equal-width partitions, then this fact follows from $\Delta x = \frac{a-b}n = -\frac{b-a}n$. A similar, but more cumbersome to write down, proof will work for general partitions as well.

Comment: @Greg its fine, but generally is presented as a definition in many textbooks